# Will torchvision.transforms.resize damage the image information?

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network, torchvision

Hi！I want to define a cubic data with a series of images, so I must resize these images to a unitified size, but I have a question about if the does would destroy the key information for subsequent extraction of the information in these images. Please give me some suggestions, thank you!

I hava used the API of torchvision.transforms.resize to realize the scaling function for unitified size images, but I don't know the does if influence the subsequent extraction of features in the images. I hope it will not affect the extraction of key features of subsequent images in CNN.

Comment: That depends on how much you scale the image, what features you’re interested in, and how big those features are.

Comment: But yes, some transforms including this one are not perfectly invertible and are lossy with respect to the original image information.